# Compiling c++ code gives an error "‘nameWindow’ was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors

I am new in openCV. I have a c++ code like below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Mat img(480,640,CV_8UC3,Scalar(255,0,0));
    if(img.empty())
    {
        cout<<"Picture can not load..."<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    nameWindow("test",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("test",img);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyWindow("test");
    return 0;
}
```

I try to compile this code in ubuntu 14.04. But when i do

```
g++ resimac.cpp
```

it gives an error:

```
error: ‘nameWindow’ was not declared in this scope
  nameWindow("test",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
                                      ^
```

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Because you have nothing named nameWIndow?

Comment: Typo => namedWindow (add a `d`)

Comment: Please stop using namespaces like this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

> nameWindow("test",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

You are missing the 'd'. The correct format should be 
namedWindow("test",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow